# How to determine the file size from an attachment to a POP3 message

Tags: c#, .net, file

I'm writing a program to read from a POP3 mailbox and upload the email message into my ticketing system.  I would like to then take the attachments and upload them as well.  I've got all the information I need except the file size.

Is there a way to determine the file size from the mail message?  I am taking the attachment, decoding the base64 encoded string and breaking it into a byte array to store in database.  If there is another way to determine the file size, I'm willing to try that too.

I'm working in C# and .NET 3.5.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What .NET library are you using for POP3 access?

Comment: @gimel http://www.codeplex.com/csharpmail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the size of the base64-decoded byte array correct for you? If so, all you need to do is calculate the size without decoding it, right?

A byte array of size N will encode to (N * 4)/3 bytes, *always rounding up*. You need to look at the last few characters of the string to work out how much to remove for rounding. Basically it should be something like:

```
string x = GetBase64DataFromWherever();
int size = (x.Length *3)/4;
if (x.EndsWith("="))
{
    size--;
}
if (x.EndsWith("=="))
{
    size--; // 1 will already have been removed by the if statement above
}
```

This is untested, but presumably you've got good test data you can try it with :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet - for the int size = (x*3)/4;  should it be x.length?  Thanks!

Comment: No problem.. This seems to be working pretty well for the file size.  Now I have to figure out how to get this library parses the attachment, but that's another question :) .  Thanks!

Comment: and I found my other problem.  Thanks for the assistance.